# How to read i2c with out i2cget command?

Tags: embedded-linux, i2c, yocto

I am currently using Kontron smarc-samx6i board and I am running this board with Yocto kernel. Here the kernel is not supporting the command `i2cget` to check i2c data to read from sensor. So, is there any other possible ways to read i2c data from the sensors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add "i2c-tools" to your image:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " i2c-tools"
```

They include `i2cget.c`.

The recipe can be found in: `/meta/recipes-devtools/i2c-tools/`

Answer (score 1):

read:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define I2C_ADDR 0x20

int main (void) {
    char buffer[1];
    int fd;

    fd = open("/dev/i2c-0", O_RDWR);

    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("Error opening file: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    if (ioctl(fd, I2C_SLAVE, I2C_ADDR) < 0) {
        printf("ioctl error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    buffer[0]=0xFF;
    write(fd, buffer, 1);

    read(fd, buffer, 1);
    printf("0x%02X\n", buffer[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

write:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define I2C_ADDR 0x20

int main (void) {
    int value;
    int fd;

    fd = open("/dev/i2c-0", O_RDWR);

    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("Error opening file: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    if (ioctl(fd, I2C_SLAVE, I2C_ADDR) < 0) {
        printf("ioctl error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    for (value=0; value<=255; value++) {
        if (write(fd, &value, 1) != 1) {
            printf("Error writing file: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        }
        usleep(100000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look into writing your own application using the i2c dev interface. See the kernel documentation on [i2c](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface).